# Error compiling sio client

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013

I've clone the project `Socket IO C++` [from Github](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/). After many attempts on compiling im getting the following error that I don't get how to solve. Does anyone have an idea on what could it be?

> error C2664:
>   'boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer,boost::asio::waitable_timer_service>::basic_waitable_timer(const
>   boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer>
>   &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'boost::chrono::milliseconds' to
>   'const
>   std::chrono::time_point < std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::system_clock::duration> 
>   &'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following post in Github solved the problem !
https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/issues/437